# Javascript mouse events not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, slider, mouseevent, drag

I'm making a little sliding bar at the top of my website. It's supposed to be somewhat like the IOS 5+ notification center slider.

HTML

```
<div id='orange'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla est velit, interdum consequat ante non, consectetur semper tortor. Aliquam convallis libero erat, a porttitor libero pretium ut. Phasellus convallis egestas tortor et fermentum. Nullam dignissim consectetur risus, in rhoncus urna venenatis eu. Donec non urna quis augue sollicitudin ornare. Aenean non faucibus nisi. Vestibulum porta quam quis massa tempus luctus. Quisque nisl nibh, feugiat id ante sed, auctor rhoncus est. Sed blandit enim sapien, in condimentum urna tristique vitae. Phasellus aliquam ipsum mattis fringilla vehicula. Mauris nec felis est. Nulla ullamcorper tellus a magna volutpat aliquet. Nunc nec venenatis sem.
    <div class='resize' onmousedown="verticalResize(document.getElementById('orange'), 6);"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#orange {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #ca4d0d;
    height: 6px;
    position: relative;
}
.resize {
    padding:0;
    height: 6px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: n-resize;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function verticalResize(element, min) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var mouseToBottom = (element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight) - event.clientY;
    document.onmousemove = function (event) {
        var target = (event.clientY + mouseToBottom) - element.offsetTop;
        if (target < min || element.offsetHeight < min) {
            element.style.height = min + "px";
        } else if (target > element.scrollHeight || element.offsetHeight > element.scrollHeight) {
            element.style.height = element.scrollHeight + "px";
        } else {
            element.style.height = target + "px";
        }
    }
    document.onmouseup = function () {
        document.onmousemove = null;
        if (element.releaseCapture) {
            element.releaseCapture();
        }
    }
    if (element.setCapture) {
        element.setCapture();
    }
}
```

Now the thing is, I got it to work like I wanted (I'm testing whatever I make in chrome until I get it perfect). Then when I where to test it in the major browsers (IE, Opera, Safari, Chrome and Firefox) it worked fine except for Firefox. It seems like the mouse events never get registered when on firefox.

Why is this? And how would I solve it?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwh9s/)

Comment: Console: ReferenceError: event is not defined, event = event || window.event;

Answer (score 1):

Your `event` is not defined.

Why are you using inline functions? I can't see the particular reason for that. 
You can handle it that way, which also solves your issue:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('resize')[0].onmousedown = function (event) {
    var element = document.getElementById('orange');
    var min = 6;
    //...
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mwh9s/1/